# Change the loading tab of tabBar in Sencha

Tags: extjs, tabs, sencha-touch, loading, tabbar

In here I want to load my window with 'tab B' without rearranging order of tabs. Normally it load with 'tab A'.

Please resolve my issue.

here is my source code:

```
Ext.define('test.view.tView', {

        extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',
        xtype: 'main',
        requires: [
            'Ext.TitleBar'
        ],
        config: {

            tabBarPosition: 'bottom',

            items: [
                {
                    title: 'tab A',
                    styleHtmlContent: true,
                    scrollable: true,

                },
                {
                    title: 'tab B',
                    pressed : true,
                    items: [{

                            xtype : 'button',
                            ui : 'round',
                            text : 'my'
                        }]
                },

                {
                    title: 'tab C',

                },
                {
                    title: 'tab D',

                }
            ]
        },
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use **[activeItem](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.0.2/#!/api/Ext.tab.Panel-cfg-activeItem)** config for your tab panel:

```
activeItem: 1,
tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
```